# How to use SSRS to retrieve HTML snippets with embedded images the easy way

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a web-app that retrieves reports from our SSRS server dynamically - we hit a URL and out pops some HTML4.0 which I stuff into a div for the user to view. I recently tried adding a report that has an embedded image (in the RDL itself) and the image doesn't make it through. What does make it through is an IMG SRC reference back to the SSRS box but we do not allow end users to hit the SSRS box directly... users query the web-app and the web-app interacts with the SSRS service. There is an option to render in MHTML (note that we typically use rs:command=RenderHTML with rs:format=HTML4.0) - the blob returned appears to be valid MIME but does not seem friendly for stuffing into a DIV... am I missing something obvious? My next step is to parse the MIME, swizzle the references and stuff the whole thing back into the page but I feel like this is the hardway. 
What is the easy way to retrieve HTML snippet reports out of SSRS with embedded images?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue.  Depending on how you implement you Reporting Services, you can get around this without having to write additional code, but you will need to be able to setup kerberos authentication to SSRS.  If you don't do this, you will need to capture the Image Stream from the SSRS Webservice.  This is done by using the RenderStream method of the webservice.  When you render an HTML report it will return an array of streamId strings.  These get passed into the RenderStream method, which in give you a byte[] in return.  You will need to swap out the sources in the HTML with new paths to the local files.  Then you will need to manage your file system.  As you do this, the number of stored images could get out of control, depending on the number of users.  So you may have to manage clean up of the images.